# How to reduce Splash Screen time

Tags: java, android, react-native, splash-screen

It takes 7-10 seconds, I want to know there is a way to reduce the time. Before I installed the splash screen, the home page is loaded in 2-3 seconds. I have installed `react-native-splash-screen` package and configured the android files automatically by using `@bam.tech/react-native-make`.

*Never tried on a real device, if you want to know.*

MainActivity.java

```
package com.myApp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme);
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "myApp";
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.myApp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
          android:launchMode="singleTask"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

splashscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/splashprimary" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/splash_image" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="SplashScreen_SplashTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/splashprimary</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/app_bg</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>

        <!-- Add the following line to set the default status bar color for all the app. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/app_bg</item>
        <!-- Add the following line to set the default status bar text color for all the app 
        to be a light color (false) or a dark color (true) -->
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
        <!-- Add the following line to set the default background color for all the app. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/app_bg</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: i usually create my own splash screen with an activity and timer. Never knew about this . Thanks for the info!

Comment: @SandrinJoy that react-native-make makes it really easy to implement, you only need a .png of the splash screen. Also do not forget hide the splash screen in your root file `SplashScreen.hide()`

Comment: so no animations? huh. That's a dull splash screen then

Comment: Yes, it only shows the .png file as a splash screen.

Comment: which method is actually practised by the professionals?

Comment: I do not know, but I think it depends on the case

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in Style.xml

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

This will remove the white screen which appears in the start.

Comment: I tried but it still takes at least 7 seconds to load up